# How to recover my ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, wubi

I am unable to boot into Ubuntu which was installed using Wubi in Windows

When I ran Ubuntu in recovery mode it gave me an error:

```
mount: mounting  /sys on /root/sys failed.
```

and then the following prompt came:

```
initramfs:
```

I logged in using a live USB and in the terminal I ran the command: `sudo fdisk -l`
its output is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x9514ed6b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda2          206848   614404095   307098624    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda3       614405925  1115090624   250342350    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda4      1147858944  1250258943    51200000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

and then I ran `sudo fsck /dev/sda1/`

its output is as follows: -

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found
fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda1
```

I also tried

`sudo ntfsck /dev/sda1/` it's output is as follows

```
Failed to access '/dev/sda1/': Not a directory
Error opening partition device: Not a directory
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use ? Can you add the full output of  `sudo fdisk -l` ? Did you also use `chkdsk` of Windows to fix errors of the Windows partitions ?

Comment: thanks for your response I have added the output of fdisk -l command.

Comment: Which live usb did you use ? The missing ntfs module is an issue of your live usb. But if you read [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info),  "it's necessary to reboot into Windows first to have it repair the Windows filesystem before the Ubuntu filesystem.", you should repair a Windows filesystem like ntfs with Windows. That is why I asked in a previous comment if you repair it with Windows. But I try an answer for your question... BTW: You should add Wubi tag to your question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to correct Windows filesystem with Windows:
   see [WubiGuide - Cannot boot into Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu)
2. Then boot into live usb and try to correct Ubuntu filesystem.
3. Type `sudo blkid` to decide which partition is your Windows partition with the Wubi disk
4. Type `sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt` to mount your Windows partition with the Wubi disk. Replace `/dev/sdax` with `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda4` depending of your decision in step 3.
5. Type `sudo e2fsck -pv /mnt/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` to check Ubuntu filesystem within Wubi disk.
6. Type `sudo mkdir /wubi` to create a folder for your Ubuntu data.
7. Type `sudo mount -o loop /mnt/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /wubi` to mount Wubi disk with your Ubuntu. All your data should be now in folder /wubi.
8. Sometimes it is necessary to perform commands within your Ubuntu system. If you need the environment of your Ubuntu system, you can type the following commands:

   `sudo mount -o bind /mnt /wubi/host`

   `sudo mount -o bind /dev /wubi/dev`

   `sudo mount -o bind /proc /wubi/proc`

   `sudo mount -o bind /sys /wubi/sys`

   `sudo chroot /wubi`

   `your commands`

   `exit`

   `sudo umount -a`

I found it at [ubuntuusers.de](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wubi/Problembehebung/#Befehlsuebersicht). It is in German but the commands are the same of course.