# Wubi installed Ubuntu 12.04 is not booting suddenly and showing GRUB prompt instead

Tags: 12.04, wubi, bootloader, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 3 years back alongside windows7 using Wubi installer. It was working very well till now but today suddenly it has stopped working after showing some errors when shutting down.

What I have tried:

I have tried every possible solution prompted by various experts at various blogs or sites. like boot-repair-disc and all.

I have found one strange thing and i am assuming this is the problem.

When I installed Ubuntu on Windows-7 using wubi-installer 3years back at that time , due to its small size (30 GB maximum), I decided to expand the "root.disc" and  I made a backup of that 30GB "rood.disc" and expanded "root.disc" to 120GB size.

today, to check whether the boot problem arises because of external factors or directly from  the "root.disc", I have replaced my "root.disc" file with 3 year old "OLDroot.disc" file, and now the system boots normally and works perfectly.

I have concluded that problem somewhere in my "root.disc" and I have used "root.disc" explorer software "ext2explore-2.2.71" to detect the corrupt file in the defective "root.disc" file.

When I compare the content of both the files,  "OLDroot.disc" (3 year old) and current  "root.disc",  I have found that the entire "boot" folder is missing within current "root.disc" while "boot" folder is present within "OLDrood.disc" file and this could be the possible reason for not working Ubuntu 12.02 and showing GRUB prompt instead.

Is there any way to copy something into "root.disc" file because using "ext2explore-2.2.71" it is possible to extract files from "root.disc" but pasting something into it is not possible and if i could able to copy the entire "boot" folder from "OLDroot.disc" file to current "root.disc" it could solve my problem, how can i do it..

Comment: @Zanna Ubuntu 12.02 not booting and  showing GRUB prompt instead.

Comment: @Zanna, i have updated my Question kindly go to the last section of my Question what exactly i want.

Comment: Why is there 14.04 tag?

Comment: @Anwar If some one is expert and able to solve problem related to  14.04,  one can assume that he might have worked on ubuntu 12.02 also. As per my understanding boot mechanism and grub at core, worked same wither it is 12.04 or 14.04.

Comment: Do you have 12.04 CD to boot?

Comment: @Anwar not CD but Live USB

Comment: Perhaps, the file system of your root.disk is corrupted. Can you try my answer from [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/817078/386067) to check and repair your file system ?

Comment: @jax were you able to fix your problem using the answer?

Comment: @Anwar Hey thanks for the solution but i have not tried yet because today is EID and its holiday in india, that Workstation belongs to my lab so i will try this solution tomorrow and hope it should work . Wish you a very happy EID.

Comment: @Anwar Hii thanks anwar for saving my data, today i am able to fix my problem.. your answer help me a lot,  i have used bit different trick because dont know why Bootable USB with Ubuntu was not working in my Workstation. So what i did i am putting in my Answer bcz it bit long.

Comment: @jax Glad that you fixed your problem and saved your data at crucial time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You have a 12.04 Live CD or bootable USB, Boot using that to Live Mode.

Then mount your 'root.disc' and 'oldroot.disc' files in two folders in Live users home folder. (I'm assuming your two files as root.disc and oldroot.disc, You'll use the exact name for them in the commands)

First make two folders

```
mkdir newroot oldroot
```

Then mount them accordingly

```
sudo mount -o loop root.disc ~/newroot 

sudo mount -o loop oldroot.disc ~/oldroot
```

Then copy all files from newroot's boot to oldroot's boot

```
sudo cp -r ~/newroot/boot ~/oldroot/
```

After copy is finished, unmount both of the files.

```
sudo umount ~/newroot
sudo umount ~/oldroot
```

Exit from live session. Make necessary adjustment to use the oldroot.disc file such as renaming. After that start your Ubuntu with the hope it is fixed.

Comment: IMHO mount command for Wubi disks are with `-o loop` e.g. `sudo mount -o loop root.disc ~/newroot`

Comment: @ngng good point. Though it is not required in newer versions.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know that it is not required.  I always see mount command for Wubi disks with -o loop and thought it was necessary. But you are right, it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my problem. I have adopted half of the trick suggested by Anwar and rest I tried with my own as given below. Hope it can help others. I don't know technically correct it is, but it solved my problem.

1. First I copied the defected "root.disk" in another partition of my hard drive using windows OS.
2. Replaced "root.disk" with "OLDroot.disc" and renamed the "OLDroot.disk" as "root.disk" so that it would recognize by boot loader as a primary drive for Ubuntu.
3. System rebooted, and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Ubuntu worked and system booted with Ubuntu absolutely fine.
4. now  corrupted  "root.disk" which was required the actual fix and moved recently into another partition, was mounted  using  command suggested my anwar.

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop root.disc ~/newroot
   ```
5. Copied "boot" folder from current Ubuntu session to corrupted "root.disk"  which was present in other partition.
6. System was booted again with windows.
7. Old "root.Disk" file replaced with fixed "root.Disk" file from other partition and system was rebooted.

Ubuntu Login Screen appeared Successfully :).......