# How to add boot folder into "root.disc" of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, boot, grub2

Accidentally i have deleted my "boot" folder which is resides within the "root.disc" (I have installed ubuntu with wubi-installer). How can i add boot folder into root.disc file from a "Backup_root.disc" file

Comment: I am  on  verge of my PhD submission may be in next week and today i lost my three year work , lots of stuffs i need to backup,  though i have many thing but its all messed up hope you can understand my condition. If it wont recover it will push me 6 month  back :( :( ;(

Comment: Is it a duplicate of your [second question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/823945/wubi-installed-ubuntu-12-04-is-not-booting-suddenly-and-showing-grub-prompt-inst)?